# Line bundles on projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C \subset \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}$ is a smooth, geometrically irreducible curve defined by degree $d$ polynomial over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Why is
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(C) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(d).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the hyperplane given by $x_0=0$. If $C$ is given by a homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$, then the Weil divisor $$C-dH=div(f/x_0^d)$$ where     $f/x_0^d$ is a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^2_k$. So in the Class group $C\sim dH$ (rationally equivalent). In the isomorphism $$Cl(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\simeq Pic(\mathbb{P}^2_k)$$  $C$ correcponds to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k}(C)$ and $dH$ corresponds to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k}(d)$.

Comment: Nice, answer! Thank you!